# Changing the font color of display header

Tags: css, fonts, colors, displaytag

I have this display column tag

```
<display:column property="geoRegion" sortProperty="geo_region" title="Geographical Region" sortable="true">
```

The sortable link appears in blue color which does not go well with my page. How should I change the color of this font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set in your CSS

```
a {
   color:#000; /*value of the color that you want*/
}
```

You can complement the `a` tag to be more specific. Depends on how it renders the html you can place some like `#table tr td a`